# Bash - cURL Get requests are slow (Relatively)

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I'm constantly querying a server for a list of items. Usually the data returned is "offers:" with a blank list, 99.999% of the time this is the data I get back from my request. So, pretty small payload.

I have a ping of 35ms pretty rock solid, jitter is about 0.2ms

But when running a single loop of requests, I get updates about every 300ms.

My goal is to make this as fast as I possibly can, so I parallelized it, running 8 of the loops. But now, I see that frequently 4 or more of the threads will seem to run simultaneously. Giving me 4 requests within 10 or 20ms of each other, and leaving periods of up to 200ms with no requests being processed.

The server I'm interfacing is of unknown specs, but it's a large company I'm interfacing with and I'd assume that the server I am communicating with is more than capable of handling anything I could possibly throw at it.

Comment: It probably is more than capable of handling said requests but this doesn't mean that you can freely flood it and expect it to handle every request. It could very well just be configured this way

Comment: are you using compressed transfer encodings? if not, that could speed it up. enable it with the `--compressed` parameter